# Adjust a Div's Style Depending on Another Div's Presence?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, function

In the snippet provided, I have 3 sections: The first contains a single image, the second has two images, and the last one has no images.

I would like for the `.image` class within the first section to be 100% in width **only** if there is no other `.image` div present.

However, once there is another `.image` div present, (as shown in the second section), I would like it to default back to 50% width.

How should I execute this?

```js
$(function() {
  $('.container > .section').each(function() {
    if (!$(this).find(".image").length) {
      $(this).before('<div class="noimage">No images to display.</div>');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 22px;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.container {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: auto;
}

.image {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  line-height: 0;
}

.image img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  padding: 10px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- 1 Image -->
<div class="container">
  <h1>Section With 1 Image:</h1>
  <div class="section">
    <div class="image"><img src="https://freeiconshop.com/wp-content/uploads/edd/pear-flat.png"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- 2 Images -->
<div class="container">
  <h1>Section With 2 Images:</h1>
  <div class="section">
    <div class="image"><img src="https://freeiconshop.com/wp-content/uploads/edd/ice-cream-cone-flat.png"></div>
    <div class="image"><img src="https://freeiconshop.com/wp-content/uploads/edd/orange-flat.png"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- No Images -->
<div class="container">
  <h1>Section With No Images:</h1>
  <div class="section"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is using ```flexbox``` a possibility? If so, I believe you'll have a simpler solution, however browser support will be limited

Comment: I guess I was looking for a JQuery solution... But `flexbox` might be a possibility.

Comment: Worked out a solution with `flexbox` here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48838047/9214076. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out a simpler solution with flexbox:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.container > .section').each(function() {
    if (!$(this).find(".image").length) {
      $(this).before('<div class="noimage">No images to display.</div>');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 22px;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.container {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  padding: 10px;
  display: block;
}

.section {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0 -5px;
}

.image {
  flex: 1 1 50%;
  line-height: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container .image:nth-of-type(n+3) {
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.image img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- 1 Image -->
<div class="container">
  <h1>Section With 1 Image:</h1>
  <div class="section">
    <div class="image"><img src="https://freeiconshop.com/wp-content/uploads/edd/pear-flat.png"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- 2 Images -->
<div class="container">
  <h1>Section With 2 Images:</h1>
  <div class="section">
    <div class="image"><img src="https://freeiconshop.com/wp-content/uploads/edd/pear-flat.png"></div>
    <div class="image"><img src="https://freeiconshop.com/wp-content/uploads/edd/ice-cream-cone-flat.png"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- 4 Images -->
<div class="container">
  <h1>Section With 4 Images:</h1>
  <div class="section">
    <div class="image"><img src="https://freeiconshop.com/wp-content/uploads/edd/pear-flat.png"></div>
    <div class="image"><img src="https://freeiconshop.com/wp-content/uploads/edd/ice-cream-cone-flat.png"></div>
    <div class="image"><img src="https://freeiconshop.com/wp-content/uploads/edd/orange-flat.png"></div>
    <div class="image"><img src="https://freeiconshop.com/wp-content/uploads/edd/burger-flat.png"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- No Images -->
<div class="container">
  <h1>Section With No Images:</h1>
  <div class="section"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could display the section as a table and the div.image as a table-cell. Then the image would resize according to the number of "cell's" (div.image's) present.

```
    div.container{
      display: 100%;
    }

    div.section{
      width: 100%;
      display: table;
    }

    div.section div.image{
      display: table-cell;
    }

    div.section div.image img{
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
    }
```

Here's a JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/ColiniloC/Lnnkpx6L/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, would you say that this method delivers better browser compatibility than flexbox?

Comment: The above seems to work in IE8 so it probably works everywhere. :-) Flexbox might be fine depending on which browsers you need to support; It could be problematic on IE 10, 11 and won't work at all in IE8,9. (https://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox)